# python line_profiler automatic

Tags: python, optimization, profile

I have a programm of which I want a line-by-line profile with multiple parameter sets.
line_profiler does what I want, at least in principle. Basically I want the profile for every parameter set. But I dont get how I could start the line_profiler from within a python script and then analyse the output directly in the same script.

My two problems are:
1) How to start the profiler from within a pythonscript (basically how to emulate the "python kernprof.py -l run.py" call
2) How to get the output of "python -m line_profiler run.py.lprof" into python to get an analysis

Cheers,
Andi

Answer (score 0):

take a look to subprocess, something like that should work ;)

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("whoami", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

(out, err) = proc.communicate()
```